# How do I know if I have permission to access the site where I received some images?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

In my web site, I must pull some images from another site. But when I try to access some of these images, I have got an error from the site.

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>E9F4E023B5D97708</RequestId>
<HostId>mgNKXX5hG2AXioZFNWbUyMZAncoB0Rr2UQMd2N3k3PcluiLy47JSP4d2XKGw2LlX++LyQwF9krU=</HostId>
</Error>
```

It's ok, I have default images. But how can I determine can I access image so if I can't, I can use a default image? When I try HEAD requests with Ajax, 
I was faced with CORS failure, so I can't understand image is accessible or not.

Comment: How are you loading the images from JS? Please share your code

Comment: For now in css: 

background-image:url('some-url'), but i want firstly load default images, then when page loading completed, i check URLs and replace them like lazy loading image